# opening one form to another form, doesn't work in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i am trying to open another from login form. but it executes only load event after that both forms get closed.

on button click from login from below is the code

Con.ConnectionString = ConnectionString

```
    Try
        Con.Open()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        ' do something with this type of exception
    Catch ex As DataException
        ' do something with this type of exception
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try


    Dim Sql As String
    Dim Pass As String = Module1.EncryptPassword(TxtPassword.Text)

    Sql = " select * from c_tpr_users where Usr_name='" & TxtUser.Text & "' and Password='" & Pass & "'"

    Dim SC As New SqlCommand
    SC.Connection = Con
    SC.CommandText = Sql

    Dim Sdr As SqlDataReader = SC.ExecuteReader()

    If Sdr.HasRows Then
        MsgBox("Login Sucess", vbOKOnly + vbInformation)


        Sdr.Close()
        SC.Dispose()
        UserNameInCustomERP = TxtUser.Text
        UserNameInERP = TxtUser.Text

        Sql = "select Year from FinYears where CONVERT(date, GETDATE())>=StartDate and  CONVERT(date, GETDATE())<=EndDate"

        SC.Connection = Con
        SC.CommandText = Sql

        Sdr = SC.ExecuteReader()

        If Sdr.HasRows Then
            If Sdr.Read() Then
                FAYear = Sdr.Item("year")
            End If
        End If
        Sdr.Close()
        SC.Dispose()
        'new form want to opend
        FrmSampleDispatch.Show()

        Me.Close()
```

kindly help me... thanks in advance

Comment: I'm guessing that your login form is the startup form for the project. If so, that's your issue. The app will exit when you close the startup form. The login form should not be the startup form. Your main form should be your startup form. Display the login form from the `Startup` event handler for the application and then cancel if the login fails. If you do that then the app will exit without creating the startup form. If you don't cancel then the app will start normally.

Comment: Check this out for a specific explanation: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?499888-WinForms-Login